# Inputting and saving 2d arrays in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, matrix, multidimensional-array, linear-algebra

I've been struggling with manual input of 2d Arrays in Java.

- Firstly, as I am creating a program concerned with matrices, is there a way of manipulating rows and columns to make the matrices look more 'natural', a.k.a. to look like a square, rather than being placed vertically in the program *(will provide screenshots, shortly).
- Secondly, how do I store a 2D array that is input manually to a matrix in the main method, which would later be used to perform operations with matrices later on in the program? For example, if a user entered a matrix, and wants to find its inverse, how do I store his input from the keyboard to be used to find the determinant (which has a separate method dealing with the stored matrix). I keep getting zeros!

Here are the code and the snapshots: 
[image: Horrid looking matrices]

Main method asks for the dimensions and provides System.out.println stuff.

```
 static void Manual(dimension){
   int n=dimension;
   int mat[][]=new int [n][n];
     Scanner scan= new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int row=0; row<n;row++)
    {for(int col=0; col<n;col++)
        {     
             mat[row][col]=scan.nextInt();

        }
        System.out.print("\n");
    }
```

Comment: I don't see any horrid looking matrix in your screenshot..., do you mean that `1 2  3 4` on separate lines that seem to be a manual input rather than the visualization of your matrix? Do you expect a grid of 4 input fields that the user can cycle through?

Comment: "I keep getting zeros!" - you should probably show us how you try to use the entered matrix. From that method (btw, the name should be lower case to avoid confusion and the parameter type is missing) is seems that you create the 2D array locally and don't return it. Try returning the array and storing the reference to that array wherever appropriate so that the other methods have access to it.

Comment: Hi Thomas, about your first comment:yes, I thought it could look nicer visually, and Yash Soni's answer helped me with that! Also, I changed the return type to int[][] and it works just fine! Thanks for your time:)

Answer (score 0):

For printing the matrix, make one helper method

```
public void printMatrix(int[][] matrix){
    int rows = matrix.length;
    int cols = matrix.length;
    for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
       for(int j=0; j<cols; j++)
           System.out.print(matrix[i][j]+" ");
       System.out.println();
    }
}
```

To answer on how to perform operations,
Use Switch case:

```
switch(inputChar){
    case 'a': computeDeterminant(); break;
    case 'b': computeInverse(); break;
    case 'c': .... ; break;
    default : .... ;
}
```

And make sure you make your matrix a static object. That will help you manipulate single object. And, you can use temp matrix to reflect the changes to the main object.

Hope this helps, 
tell me if I missed something.